# MCRYPT mode is generating slashes

Tags: php, encryption, kohana-3

I'm new to this encryption thing, so i'm not realy sure how to format my question.

Anyways i'm using framework called `kohana` and for encryption it uses three things:

`key`, `cipher`, `mode` so my problem is that when it encodes some string sometimes i get `/` in encryption like this `fclzSev6DVfOk2Z/BSSi4dRYFn4t` and i don't want that so my guess is that i should change `mode` which right now is `MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB` so if i'm right what mode do i have to use?

Comment: because i'm using encrypted string in my url and if there is slashes it creates extra params for my get method and basicly it all becames messed up

Comment: Then urlencode it, like you would any other thing that needs to be encoded in a url.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Francis Avila notes, the encrypted output seems to be [Base64-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and so may contain slashes and plus signs (and possibly equals signs at the end) in addition to letters and numbers.

You can safely replace those signs with something else, *as long as* you remember to change them back before decoding.  The PHP [`strtr()` function](http://php.net/strtr) is handy for this.  For example, here's how to convert a string from normal Base64 to the RFC 4648 URL-safe Base64 variant and back:

```
$url_safe_base64 = strtr( $base64_string, "+/", "-_" );

$base64_string = strtr( $url_safe_base64, "-_", "+/" );
```

Answer (score 2):

`mode` has absolutely nothing to do with whether the generated output has slashes, but specifies what mode of encryption `mcrypt` should use. If you don't know what it's for use the default.

The reason there are slashes is that Kohana's `encode()` method will encode the binary output from the encryption in base64, which may contain slashes.

You can `str_replace()` the slashes with something else, but this will probably create more problems and headaches than it solves.

Comment: yeah i guess if i would replace slashes later i would have a lot of problems decoding it